# downloadlink in wicket check for duplicate file name?

Tags: duplicates, download, wicket

Lets say one user of a wicket application downloads a file.. this process starts inside the imodel and a new file is created with data written to it, then the file is deleted per downloadlink setting.

Now what if another user chooses to create a data file using the same page and functionality,  but the first user's instance is still running and processing the file..  is there ever a chance that if the file created has the same name for all users but is created and deleted will have a concurrency issue?

If so what is the best way to prevent this?

Basically what I have is a search modal, and I give the user to extract the results to an excel file..  that I create. Once the downloadlink is selected. When the user downloads the file, it is then deleted by the downloadlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store each temp file in a folder with the session id. Get the session id like this:

```
Session.get().getId();
```

Each user will download their files from their own unique session folder so file names don't matter anymore.

Comment: You can also create a custom class that extends HttpSessionStore and add it to your Application. You can use the destroy() function to remove the folder where the temporary files generated  during that session. That way you can also reuse generated filed during a session.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to skip the creation of a file entirely and generate it using `Stream`s and a `ResourceLink`

For example

Writing POI (Streaming) to OutputStream:

```
class FileProducer
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void writeToStream( OutputStream stream ) throws IOException
    {
        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook( 1000 ); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk  
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet( this.pageName );

        int index = 0;
        int rowIndex = 0;
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow( rowIndex );

        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell( index );
        cell.setCellValue( fieldName );

            ..
        wb.write( stream );
    }
}
```

And a FileProducerResource (exending Wicket's `AbstractResource`)

```
public class FileProducerResource extends AbstractResource
{
    FileProducer f;

    public FileProducerResource( FileProducer f )
    {
        this.f = f;
    }

    @Override
    protected ResourceResponse newResourceResponse( Attributes attributes )
    {
        Injector.get().inject( this.f );
        this.f.prepare();

        final String fileName = this.f.getFileName();

        ResourceResponse resourceResponse = new ResourceResponse();
        resourceResponse.setContentType( "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" );
        resourceResponse.setCacheDuration( Duration.NONE );
        resourceResponse.setFileName( fileName );
        resourceResponse.setWriteCallback( new WriteCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void writeData( Attributes attributes ) throws IOException
            {
                OutputStream outputStream = attributes.getResponse().getOutputStream();

                FileProducerResource.this.f.writeToStream( outputStream );
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } );
        return resourceResponse;
    }
```

}

This `Resource` is used in a Wicket `ResourceLink`

Comment: Thanks Rob. I tried something similar. Excel Poi class only accepts a subclass of OutputStream, so I used ByteArrayOutputStream. Then to get it to be readable by Wicket's IResourceStream I had to wrap the results into a StringResourceStream... And somewhere down the line this causes an issue with the excel file. It opens fine but with a warning, and also creates a duplicate column A. So the data seems to get corrupted at some point. Not sure of a better way using Excel POI to do it.

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong, because I also use POI to do generate files on the fly. I will add a bit of code to my answer in a minute.

Comment: Yep, definitely wasn't doing it this way haha. There are a few classes I am unfamiliar with here. But this seems like an elegant solution for me to play around with and browse the API. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

I would create the new file where the data is written as TempFile instead of a general File:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(<a base name of file as String>, "tmp", <folder as File>);
```

This creates a File like "Name24144343.temp" and it is always going to be uniqe, OS independently. Also you can override the name of the downloaded file so the user will see nothing if this filename.

To be more specific, this is how you write the file:

```
protected File getBytesAsTempFile(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    File file;
    File uploadFolder = getYourUploadFolder();
    file = File.createTempFile("functionX", "tmp", uploadFolder);
    FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fileOuputStream.write(data);
    fileOuputStream.close();
    return file;
}
```

For download link:

```
DownloadLink downloadLink = new DownloadLink("downloadFileBtn", <model of your temp file>, <model of your file's name when downloaded>);
```

Finally you can remove this file as usual. (No matter it is a temp file, it won't be deleted automatically!)